# How does the universal approximation theorem connect to classification problems?

Tags: universal-approximation-theorem

Feedforward Neural Networks are used a lot for classification problems and they seem to do a good job. How can this be justified?

As the universal approximation theorem for neural networks assumes there is continuity, which clearly is not the case with classifications?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364917/what-is-required-for-neural-network-to-approximate-discontinuous-function Also: the step function used in two-class classification can be approximated by continuous sigmoid-like functions to any accuracy [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475415002554) which is trivially generalized to multi-class classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* continuity.

Remember that a neural network doing “classification” actually outputs probabilities of class membership. Therefore, the neural network is a continuous function between the feature space and the interval $[0,1]$, and the universal approximation theorem applies.